# jQuery text() function remove <br> from the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing some problem with jQuery, I am using the next command to catch text from inside a div:

```
var text = $("#user_content").text();
```

but the action remove the `<br>` tags from the text? any idea?

Thanks
Shai

Comment: `var text = $("#user_content").html();` ???  `.text()` method strip out tags, returning only text

Comment: Yes, html should work!

Comment: When faced with problems of this kind it is always helpful to [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com) which [in this case](http://api.jquery.com/text/) clearly illustrate that this is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `var text = $("#user_content").html();` instead of `var text = $("#user_content").text();`